# How to extract nested Json in Swift

Tags: swift

how do I extract this type of nested json in swift?

JSON

```
{  
   "item":{  
      "id":33,
      "title":"Article 5",
      "subtitle":"Tasing  123",
      "body":"Hello world " ,
      "date":"15/04/2013 11:48"
   }
}
```

Comment: please add the complete json

Comment: That's not very complex and there is no array in the sample JSON. Braces represent a dictionary. And **never** load data with synchronous API like `Data(contentsOf` not even in an asynchronous dispatch queue.

Comment: It's recommended to use `Codable` protocol for working with JSON. A simple google search ***JSON parsing in swift 4*** will get you multiple results of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Swift4 Codable

```
struct Items: Codable {
    let item: Item
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title, subtitle, body, date: String
}
```

And use it with

```
let items = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Items.self, from: jsonData)
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Thanks.  I will try Codable.

Comment: Thanks Prashant, your solution works and it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is another example of `Codable`, except, it converts the `date` `String` to a `Date` value. It's one of my pet hates, personally, you should avoid maintaining date/time values as a `String` ... just don't get me started.

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let body: String
    let date: Date
}

struct ItemList: Codable {
    let item: Item
}

let formatter = DateFormatter()
// 15/04/2013 11:48
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
// May want to include the timezone, since it's unspecified
// yet another pet hate

let jsonString = """
{
        "item":{
                "id":33,
                "title":"Article 5",
                "subtitle":"Tasing  123",
                "body":"Hello world " ,
                "date":"15/04/2013 11:48"
        }
}
"""
let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
    let items = try decoder.decode(ItemList.self, from: jsonData)
    items.item.id
    items.item.title
    items.item.subtitle
    items.item.body
    items.item.date
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

You can find more information at [Ultimate Guide to JSON Parsing with Swift 4](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/)